# How to convert a list into vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have extracted odd_ratios from fisher test as follow. How can i incorporate `unlist`in the following code. or there is some other solution too.

```
fisher_or <- apply(ids_df, 1, function(i) tryCatch(fisher.test(table(class.df[,i]))$estimate, error = function(e) NA_real_))

class(fisher_or)
[1] "list"

head(fisher_or)

[[1]]
odds ratio 
 0.2416209 

[[2]]
odds ratio 
 0.8681188 

[[3]]
odds ratio 
         0 

[[4]]
odds ratio 
  3.743399 

[[5]]
odds ratio 
  2.256228
```

The issue is i just want to extract numerical values as a list from this. ás my ultimate goal is to bind this with my dataframe and pvalues like this.

```
edge_table<- cbind(ids_df, fisher_pvalues, fisher_or)
```

I try following but its not working..

```
fisher_OR<- do.call(rbind, fisher_or)
edge_table<- cbind(ids_df, fisher_pvalues, fisher_OR)
```

Note: class(fisher_pvalues)

```
[1] "numeric"

class(ids_df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Could you include `com`, `ids_df`, and `class.df` in your post, using `dput()`?

Comment: You can `unlist` your output; `unlist(fisher_or)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding what's going on, how about something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
class.df <- data.frame(
  A = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  B = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  C = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  D = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
)

ids_df <- t(combn(names(class.df), 2))
fisher_tests <- apply(ids_df, 1, function(i) tryCatch(fisher.test(table(class.df[,i])), error = function(e) NA_real_))
edge_table <- cbind(ids_df, bind_rows(lapply(fisher_tests, "[", c("p.value", "estimate"))))
edge_table
#>   1 2   p.value  estimate
#> 1 A B 0.2126488 1.7706623
#> 2 A C 1.0000000 0.9267634
#> 3 A D 0.2124925 1.7591799
#> 4 B C 0.5473441 1.3593715
#> 5 B D 0.8427368 0.9082905
#> 6 C D 1.0000000 1.0494569
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi. btw the problem seems to be solved at the moment or at R terminal. But when i export it as write.csv The last column (estimate) values looks like  c(`odds ratio` = 0.791974114656919)

Comment: @Aryh I updated the answer to produce a data frame that will export more cleanly.

Comment: I am getting error. Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must have names.

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must have names.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─base::cbind(...)
 2. │ └─base::cbind(deparse.level, ...)
 3. │   └─base::data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)
 4. └─dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(fisher_tests, "[", c("p.value", "estimate")))
 5.   └─rlang::abort(msg)